# Swift- Converting Index path array to Int array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, indexpath

I'm trying to produce an array of selected values from a UICollectionView in swift 4. Im using the `self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems` method which returns the selected items as an Array of type index path. For example if elements 0 and 2 were selected, it returns [[0, 0], [0, 2]] I'd like to know how to process this into an array of type Int to store it as [0,2].

I've been trying for hours any any help would be GREATLY appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use map function for this:

```
guard let indexPaths: [IndexPath] = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems else { return }
let indexes = indexPaths.map({ $0.item })
```

Or Force Unwrap:

```
let indexes = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!.map{ $0.item }
```

Another option as suggested on comment section

```
let indexes = (collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems ?? []).map{ $0.row }
```

Comment: Technically it’s `.item` for a collection view.

Comment: Perfect, just what i was after. Thank you so much!

Comment: `?? []` would be safer than force unwrapping.

Comment: NEVER force unwrap for the love of god!

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin Never say never. There are plenty of legitimate cases where force-unwrapping is perfectly fine. The trick is knowing when.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it easily with `map`:

```
let arrayOfIndexPathItems = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.map({ $0.item })
```

Be sure to use `item`s property of the `IndexPath`, since you are working with `collectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is absolutely correct! This is the same thing but just longer and maybe more understandable version for someone who's not familiar with the map function

```
let indexes = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.map { (indexPath) -> Int in
return indexPath.item }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use compactMap is cleaner.

```
let newIndexedData = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.compactMap { yourArray[$0.row] } ?? []
```